# Nested loops implementation

Tags: java, loops

I have just started learning java and seeking help how to properly implement nested loops to get it working correctly.

Increment this Clock by 1 second. Minutes and hours updated as needed

```
public void increment () {
    if (seconds < 59)
      seconds = seconds + 1;
    else
      seconds = 0;
      if (seconds <= 0)
           if (minutes < 59)
                minutes = minutes + 1;
           else
                minutes = minutes;
                if (minutes <= 0)
                  if (hours < 23)
                     hours = hours + 1;
                  else
                     hours = 0;
```

This code doesn't work how it intend to be.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Always **always** use brackets around your if statements. Doing so makes your code much easier to read and makes it harder to make mistakes. Also, it will fix your issues here.

Comment: I think I got it, I'll give it a go and see if it works. Cheers!

Comment: where is loop here?

Comment: My apologies, It not a loop. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    increment(19, 43, 59);
    increment(23, 59, 59);
    increment(7, 19, 45);
}

public static void increment(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    if (seconds < 59) {
        seconds = seconds + 1;
    } else {
        seconds = 0;
        if (minutes < 59) {
            minutes = minutes + 1;
        } else {
            minutes = 0;
            if (hours < 23) {
                hours = hours + 1;
            } else {
                hours = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}
```

Output:

```
19:44:0
0:0:0
7:19:46
```

Please note, this is just an example which you can exploit as per your need.